# Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, macos, batch-file, path, classpath

I have a source folder (src) containing a jar file and many other folders of java codes. I have made a batch file which executes the following command perfectly fine while being in the "src" folder.

```
    java -mx6g -cp .:trove.jar testing.Tester /somepath/myfile.txt
```

However, when I want to execute this batch file from a different path, even if I add the complete  address, it still doesn't work. For instance:

```
    java -mx6g -cp .:/Programs/src/trove.jar testing.Tester /somepath/myfile.txt
```

Even changing to this doesn't work:

```
    java -mx6g -cp .:/Programs/src/trove.jar /Programs/src/testing/testing.Tester /somepath/myfile.txt
```

I get the error: Error: Could not find or load main class testing.Tester.

Comment: do you have `main` method in this jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may help you:
Syntax for "executable" JAR files:

```
java [ <option> ... ] -jar <jar-file-name> [<argument> ...]
```

e.g.

```
java -Xmx100m -jar /usr/local/acme-example/listuser.jar fred
```

Class and Classpaths are specified in the `MANIFEST` of the `JAR` file

You have to give fully specified path

```
java [option]/Programs/src/:/Programs/src/trove.jar testing.Tester /AbsolutePath/fileName.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

the dot at the start of the classpath means current directory (src). you may need to fully specify that path as well.

```
java -mx6g -cp /Programs/src/:/Programs/src/trove.jar testing.Tester /somepath/myfile.txt
```